# ListView Dividers and Non-Clickable Items

Tags: android, listview, clickable, divider

All,

I would like to show a divider in a list and want to make the item not clickable but not look grayed out. I tried setting my xml layout to not clickable and not enabled when i inflated it but it did not work. below is my code.

```
private static final String[] items = { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit",
    "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
    "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam", "vel",
    "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque",
    "augue", "purus","Afghanistan", "Albania",
    "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia",
    "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin",
    "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil",
    "British Indian Ocean Territory", "British Virgin Islands",
    "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cote d'Ivoire",
    "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands",
    "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
    "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia",
    "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia",
    "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
    "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
    "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt",
    "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia",
    "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji",
    "Finland", "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France",
    "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories",
    "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece",
    "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala",
    "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti",
    "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong",
    "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq",
    "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
    "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya",
    "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Madagascar",
    "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta",
    "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius",
    "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia",
    "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
    "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles",
    "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria",
    "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
    "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama",
    "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines",
    "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
    "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe",
    "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia",
    "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
    "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia",
    "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa",
    "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
    "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname",
    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland",
    "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand",
    "The Bahamas", "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga",
    "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan",
    "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
    "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
    "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam",
    "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia",
    "Zambia", "Zimbabwe" };

    TextView selection;
    ListView list;
    MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();


    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem(items[i]);
        if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("separator " + (i+1));
        }
    }



    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            int type;
            type = mAdapter.getItemViewType(arg2);

            if (type == 0){
                selection.setText("item");
            }

            if (type == 1){
                selection.setText("divider");
            }


        }
    });

}

class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM =0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);

        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                break;

            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
             holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
             holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
             holder.layout.setEnabled(false);
             holder.textView.setEnabled(false);


             break;


            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;


    }

}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public LinearLayout layout;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

---

I believe I found my answer. What I mean by not working was that the divider was clickable. What I had to do was override in my adapter the allItemsEnabled method to return false and create a condition in the isEnabled method to return false for dividers. Here is the adapter code rewritten.

```
 public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);

        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //to make dividers not clickable
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {

        return false;
    }

    //to make dividers not clickable
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if(type==0){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                break;

            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
             holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
             holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            // holder.layout.setEnabled(false);
            //holder.textView.setEnabled(false);


             break;


            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;


    }

}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public LinearLayout layout;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `it did not work`? What is happening when you use the code you wrote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer myself. What I mean by not working was that the divider was clickable. What I had to do was to override in my adapter the `areAllItemsEnabled` method to return false and create a condition in the `isEnabled` method (see the second half of the original question).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is related to the `ClickListener` you are adding, since you are are putting in the XML that wont be clickable but after you set your `ContentView` you are putting this line:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... }
```

wich makes the list clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Redering to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234938/2852865) of another post, you just have to set the `OnClickListener` on the `View` that shouldn't be clickable to `null`. So you would call: `view.setOnClickListener(null)`. Of course you need the reference to the view to do this...