# Non-clickable Listview Item with Visible Divider

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, adapter, clickable

I would like to disable clicking of a Listview item.  One solution is to override `areAllItemsEnabled()` to always return false, and `isEnabled()` to return false for a particular position.  However, this causes the divider lines around the particular Listview item to disappear.  A few people suggested returning true for `areAllItemsEnabled()` and false for `isEnabled()`, but this is not working for me.  I am hesitant to place a divider line in manually because I would need to add a parent layout to the item XML.

Is there a way to set a Listview item to be non-clickable and still retain

Comment: put this line in your code mList.setItemsCanFocus(false);

Comment: I have items in my Listview rows that need focus, it sounds like that will disable them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is exactly the opposite of what you were told to do.
You should return false in `areAllItemsEnabled()` and just delete your override of `isEnabled()`.
It works perfectly for me and I was also struggling with that issue yesterday.

All items will not be clickable since `areAllItemsEnabled() == false` but the divider will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, but overwriting these Adapter methods seemed ugly. Then one post struck me with an idea, that had worked before already. On the view that shouldn't be clickable just call `view.setOnClickListener(null)`.

Boom, maybe this is a workaround rather than a real solution, but it works. I have to note that I added dividers programmatically to the `ListView` footer, so I had the reference to the dividers and I could simply set the `OnClickListener` to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

On the individual `View`, trying setting it to not be clickable: `view.setClickable(false)`. If that doesn't work, try `view.setFocusable(false)`.